# Filtrar bits altos y bits bajos en C

Tags: c

Tengo una variable int en C que quiero filtrar sus 16 bits altos y sus 16 bits bajos, pero no tengo claro como hacerlo, he planteado esta opción:

```
//filtrar 16 bits altos
x=variable ^ 23;            
//filtrar 16 bits bajos
y=variable & 23;
```

Es correcto esto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El acento circunflejo (`^`) es el *xor* a nivel binario. *Xor* es verdadero cuando ambos operandos son diferentes:

```
| operando 1 | operando 2 | resultado |
+------------+------------+-----------+
|    falso   |    falso   |    falso  |
|    falso   |  verdadero | verdadero |
| verdadero  |    falso   | verdadero |
| verdadero  |  verdadero |    falso  |
```

El et (`&`) es el *and* a nivel binario. *And* es verdadero cuando ambos operadores son verdaderos.

```
| operando 1 | operando 2 | resultado |
+------------+------------+-----------+
|    falso   |    falso   |    falso  |
|    falso   |  verdadero |    falso  |
| verdadero  |    falso   |    falso  |
| verdadero  |  verdadero | verdadero |
```

23<sub>10</sub> es 0000000000010111<sub>2</sub> así que ni con *xor* ni con *and* ni con *23* podrás separar los bits altos de los bajos usando esos operadores y ese número.

---

Prueba usando 4294901760<sub>10</sub> y 65535<sub>10</sub>:

```
//filtrar 16 bits altos
x=variable & 0xffff0000;            
//filtrar 16 bits bajos
y=variable & 0x0000ffff;
```

Comment: Al ser 32 bits, ¿no debería ser `& 0xFFFF0000` y `& 0x0000FFFF`?

Comment: Quiere filtrar 16 bits, no 32.

Comment: Hasta donde entendí, filtrar los 16 bits altos de 32 y los 16 bajos de 32. ¿No?

Comment: Oh, tienes razón, lo edito.

Answer (score 2):

Es cosa de usar el operador & (*bit-wise and*) con las máscaras apropiadas.

Para los 16 bits inferiores, usar `0x0000FFFF`; para los 16 superiores, `0xFFFF0000`

En este ejemplo, dividimos un entero de 32 bits en su parte superior e inferior. Para comprobación, usamos el operador |, (*bit-wise or*) para juntarlas y ver si retornamos al valor original.

Para obtener propiamente los 16 bits superiores, debemos descartar los 16 bits inferiores, para la cual usamos el operador ">>" (`shift right`), que desplaza los bits hacia la derecha en la cantidad de posiciones indicada.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
    int32_t x = 0x12345678;
    int32_t x_sup = x & 0xFFFF0000;
    int32_t x_inf = x & 0x0000FFFF;
    
    printf("%x %x %x\n", x, x_sup, x_inf);
    
    int y = x_sup | x_inf;
    printf("%x\n", y);
    
    int z = x >> 16;
    printf("%x", z);
}
```

produce:

```
12345678 12340000 5678
12345678
1234
```