# Variable int que contiene dos datos (bits altos y bits bajos)

Tags: c

Tengo un int llamado 'datos' donde los 16 bits altos indican un valor 'a' y los 16 bits bajos indican un valor 'b'. Para obtener el valor de a y b hago esto:

```
//filtrar bits, 16 bits altos
a=datos ^ 0xffff0000;           
//filtrar bits, 16 bits bajos
b=datos & 0x0000ffff;
```

Entiendo que hasta aquí es correcto, si ahora quisiera aumentar el valor 'a' de dentro de la variable datos en 1, debería hacer lo siguiente?

```
variable=variable+0x00010000;
```

Comment: ¿Por qué para sacar los altos estás usando XOR en vez de AND? Yo habría hecho `a = (datos & 0xffff0000) >> 16` (el desplazamiento es para dejar ese valor en la parte baja, por tanto como un entero "normal"  con el que ya puedes operar normalmente, por ejemplo, `a++`)

Comment: Creo que esto ya había quedado claro en tu otra [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/400646/filtrar-bits-altos-y-bits-bajos-en-c/400649?noredirect=1#comment716990_400649), no?

Comment: ¿Por qué preguntas dos veces la misma cosa? [Filtrar bits altos y bits bajos en C](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/400646/filtrar-bits-altos-y-bits-bajos-en-c/400649?noredirect=1#comment716990_400649)

Comment: @CandidMoe era por no mezclar cosas, mi duda es como incrementar la variable ahora (por ejemplo 'a' o 'b')

Comment: @SuperG280 era por no mezclar cosas, mi duda es como incrementar la variable ahora

Comment: Bueno, `a` sigue siendo una variable entera. Tiene un valor y puedes operar con ella. Cómo llegó a ese valor es irrelevante.

Comment: Ya, pero es que así no se extraen los bits más altos. Tienes que extraerlos bien, desplazarlos como te ha dicho @abulafia en su comentario, y luego simplemente sumarle 1.

Comment: @abulafia lo que yo quería hacer es aumentar el valor de los bits altos antes de extraerlos en a, no se si me explique bien

Comment: Entonces sí, sumar `0x00010000` como tú dijiste.